# Installing Mysql Workbench on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql-workbench, mariadb

I have installed MariaDb as its supported by Ubuntu community , mentioned in release note of latest LTS.

After that I tried to install Mariadb-client , that too installed successfully, after that its good to have GUI tool So decided to install MySql-workbench from both Ubuntu-SOftware-Center and via Terminal but it prompted errors mentioned below-

**Error via Ubuntu-Software-Center-**

```
 This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.
 mysql-workbench: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but 1:2.24.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
             Depends: libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7) but 1:8.31-2ubuntu2 is to be installed
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
             Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 6.0.8+dfsg-2) but 6.0.8+dfsg-2 is to be installed.
```

**Error via Terminal-**

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    mysql-workbench : Depends: mysql-client
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This one has become confirmed bug on launchpad as mentioned [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-workbench/+bug/1287424)

On the official website of My-sql , the versions of workbench are only available till saucy (13.10) , So how can I install it.

**UPDATE 1**

Added the following lines in */etc/apt/sources.list*

```
# MariaDB 10.0 repository list - created 2014-04-19 11:47 UTC
# http://mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
deb http://mirror.mephi.ru/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://mirror.mephi.ru/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu trusty main
```

No change , still same issue. There is some problems between trusty and version 10.1.10 of Mariadb . So tried

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18=10.1.10-mariadb1~trusty mysql-common=10.1.10-mariadb1~trusty
```

And its output is -

```
E: Version '10.1.10-mariadb1~trusty' for 'libmysqlclient18' was not found
E: Version '10.1.10-mariadb1~trusty' for 'mysql-common' was not found
```

So the thing is simple it could not find it . though its there on the official website.

**UPDATE 2**

Removed MariaDB 10.1.10 , but the problem is still same with MariaDB 5.5.37.

Comment: I think Mysql is in conflict with MariaDB

Comment: Here's a link to the already reported bug causing this.
It is already fixed and scheduled for 6.1.7
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72729

Comment: simply try this :  ``sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench``

Answer (score 6):

I got around it by using the latest community version and removing mysql-client from the depends

Assuming mariadb is already installed

Download mysql workbench from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/ (version for 13.10 on 14.04 is fine)

From the directory the file is downloaded run:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench mysql-workbench-data

dpkg-deb -x mysql-workbench-community-6.*.deb tmp_mysql-workbench
dpkg-deb --control mysql-workbench-community-6.*.deb tmp_mysql-workbench/DEBIAN
sed -i -e 's/mysql-client, //' tmp_mysql-workbench/DEBIAN/control
dpkg -b tmp_mysql-workbench mysql-workbench-community_patched.deb

sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_patched.deb
```

Comment: Great! just remove the trailing comma and space on the regex (4th line). In my case I replaced it with 'mysql-client-5.6'

Comment: Worked for 6.1.6 workbench and x64 ubuntu 14.04. Thnx!

Comment: That link no offers download for Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 6):

The link to download direct version for 14.04 is here http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-workbench-community-6.1.7-1ubu1404-amd64.deb

Comment: worked like a charm.

Comment: It worked on my ubuntu 14.04. No additional changed needed.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug and should be fix but it's a temporary solution:

1. Unpack mysql-workbench-community-6.1.4-1ubu1310-amd64.deb in a folder.
2. Change the file "DEBIAN/control", replace "mysql-client" to "mysql-client-5.6".
3. Go to the terminal and make a new ".deb":

   > dpkg -b mysql-workbench-community-6.1.4-1ubu1310-amd64/

**Done! Now you can install from the new deb file.**

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded .deb from the official site (13.10), and I haven't got problem.

But I have mysql-server, not mariadb

Comment: yeah first of all am talking about 14.04 thats not available on official site for .deb file , secondly I have used that with ubuntu 13.10 too and it was working fine , third thing I want to know is there any work arround for this.  Last thing gain some repo because this is not an answer just cant be considered a answer in any manner  , you can comment it after gaining some.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 14.04 to.
I think you should use mysql-server raither than mariadb

Comment: this will be my last option .. I will try to fix it, and wait for an answer till then.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the 6.2.3-1ubu1404 version which did not contain "mysql-server" string at all. However because of unmet dependencies, I couldn't have installed.

Somehow, I tried to install the requirements manuall by

```
# sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a libtinyxml2.6.2 libzip2 python-paramiko libproj0 proj-data
```

I worked.

My actual error was this one:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.2.3-1ubu1404-amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-workbench-community.
(Reading database ... 221745 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench-community-6.2.3-1ubu1404-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (6.2.3-1ubu1404) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0); however:
  Package libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libtinyxml2.6.2; however:
  Package libtinyxml2.6.2 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libzip2 (>= 0.10); however:
  Package libzip2 is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on python-paramiko; however:
  Package python-paramiko is not installed.
 mysql-workbench-community depends on libproj0; however:
  Package libproj0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community
dincer@dincerExp:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.2.3-1ubu1404-amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 223036 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-workbench-community-6.2.3-1ubu1404-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (6.2.3-1ubu1404) over (6.2.3-1ubu1404) ...
Setting up mysql-workbench-community (6.2.3-1ubu1404) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
```

Comment: m really very sorry but i dont have ubuntu installed at the moment .. So i ll try it after sometime time and then let u know ..

Comment: just try same on debian which might even work. They are all deb repositories. I doubt the version numbers may match. But just try and let us know what happened.